# Recompile library in Xcode

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5, armv7

I have two questions basically.

Scenario is that I have a(n) NMI Payment Gateway SDK

1. the SDK or library won't work under simulator environment. Though it is logically right since the sdk is for reading mag data I can't test other parts of my app on a simulator ( And I have limited resource on device ). Is there a way to recompile the sdk or based on my research how can I create a static library so that I can generate a i386 architecture based sdk. Or better yet is there a way that I can check if environment is i386 then don't load the sdk?
2. I tried creating a(n) app using the SDK mentioned above. I would like to run it using an iPhone5s device and arch (armv64, armv7 and armv7s) but it says 'undefined symbols for armv7'. Would there be a way to somehow recompile the sdk and enable it to run on newer architecture?

Any help is much appreciated. THANKS

Comment: So you are using the SDK currently as a compiled static library?  If you have the sources (which you imply you do) then add the source as a separate static library project (using an Xcode Workspace) and Xcode will compile the SDK for whatever arch is required by the project.

Comment: @trojanfoe I've googled that, but what puzzles me is can you just create a static library project add the SDK files ( header files and .a file) then compile?

Comment: No, you must have the source.

Comment: @trojanfoe that would be the header files and the compiled library file .a right? or not? because that is the only file(s) I have for that library.

Answer (score 0):

We use different targets for simulator and for device, and in code use macro  `TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR`.

example:

```
#if (TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR)
NSLog(@"device");
#else 
NSLog(@"simulator");
#endif
```